# Select & Insert across multiple databases with MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, data-migration

I have 2 identical tables in 2 different databases that reside on the same server. What would be the best way to copy data from table to another?

Comment: Why do you have redundant data like that in the first place?

Comment: @NullUserException I know that was an old comment, but it's useful for when wanting to extract subsets of data into a separate database for testing/debugging.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use:

```
INSERT INTO db1.table1
SELECT *
  FROM db2.table2 t2
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                    FROM db1.table1 t1
                   WHERE t1.col = t2.col)
```

The exists is simplified, but you left out if there's a primary key/auto_increment to worry about/etc.

Comment: what if db1 and db2 are on different ip addresses?

Answer (score 3):

Just to elaborate slightly on OMG Ponies' answer, you can use **any** `WHERE` clause, like so:

```
INSERT INTO db1.tablename
SELECT *
FROM db2.tablename src
WHERE src.lastlogin >= '2013-10-31 07:00:00'
```