# Insert data from one DB into another with where condition

Tags: mysql

I am trying to transfer data from one database to another in the same server in the condition that one field in the old DB is equivalent to a field in the new DB

I can mention that the two databases have complete different structure.

Here is my script:

```
INSERT INTO newDB.myTable (field) select oldField FROM oldDB.table WHERE id= newDB.myTable (field);
```

I get this error:

ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION newDB.myTable does not exist

Comment: check the spelling of db name and table name

Comment: are you sure the newBD has the table myTable ?

Comment: I think that the problem comes here `WHERE id= newDB.myTable (field)`. Try with `WHERE id=field`

Comment: I checked the spelling many times! i don't think it's the case

Comment: @Alee it seems like this! i tried it now i get ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'field' in 'where clause'

Comment: the same unknown column 'myTable.field' error

Comment: field must be value(s). For example `WHERE id=1` or if you have many values `WHERE id in (value1, value2,...)`.It can't be a column name.

Comment: Thing is i need to transfer only the data that meet this condition! which is the value of one field in old DB is equivalent to the a field in new DB! i don't have constant values!

Comment: so try this. `WHERE id in (select id from oldDB.table)`

Comment: You think this will insert the value in the row where the two fields match in newDB and oldDB!? i think this will insert the value in all rows since the id will always be there in the set result of the select

Comment: You can get the idea from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3399710/1908331)

Answer (score 0):

```
newDB.myTable (field)
```

Should be:

```
newDB.myTable.field
```

(The brackets make MySQL think myTable is a function)

Comment: Error in SQL syntax near '.field'! it doesn't work unfortunately!

Comment: 'field' needs to be the name of the field used in your foreign key :)